# How to sort using foreign key field in django and avoid multiple results of same row

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I want to sort Groups with their 'is_favorite' boolean field from model GroupUser. I have two models GroupUser where there is a foreign key to Group model, now when I query  `Group.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('groupuser__group_id__is_favorite')`
I get groups multiple times. I tried to user `distict()` on final queryset still no luck. Pls suggest any other way or possible solution. TIA.

````
class Group(models.Model):
 
    group_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=250)

    context_type = models.ForeignKey(
        "contenttypes.ContentType",
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="content_type")

    context = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,
        null=True)
        
    privacy_type = models.ForeignKey(
        "commans.PrivacyType",
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="group_privacy_id")
    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        help_text="Is Group Active")


class GroupUser(models.Model):

    group = models.ForeignKey(
        "Group",
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="groupuser_group_id")
    
    user=models.ForeignKey(
        "auth_module.User",
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    

    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, 
        blank=True,
        null=True)
```
````

Comment: Can you include the models in your question. Which database are you using?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington : Yes, updated

Answer (score 0):

We can use an annotation to count the number of favourites each Group has. Then we can use this annotation to order by

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Group.objects.filter(
    is_active=True
).annotate(
    total_favorites=Sum('groupuser_group_id__is_favorite')
).order_by(
    '-total_favorites'
)
```

Comment: Sorry but what is happenign is i am getting groups sorted first but when is_favorite value is changed and the api for same is called again, sorting is not working. I have a user specific is_favorite row for each group thus , count , sum, max, may not be used.